# File upload freezes with files above 100MB

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, php

So I have a website where you can upload files,
when you start an upload a progress bar pops up.

If a file or group of files selected at once is less than 100MB the upload goes through and completes without a problem.

If they are over 100MB the upload freezes at 0%.

I have set

> post_max_size = 200G

> upload_max_filesize = 200G

The code I use for the upload works with any file on my PC using XAMPP.

For my server I use a RaspberryPI 4.

Any help with solving this problem would be appreciated.

Also the php code:

```php
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION))session_start();
function returnMSG($status, $message){
    $result = array();
    $result['status'] = $status;
    $result['error'] = $message;
    return $result;
}
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    include "data.php";
    $limit = $fileLimit[$_SESSION['role']];
    $currData = 0;
    include "connect.php";
    $conn = connect("upload"); // custom function
    if(!isset($_POST['pF']))$_POST['pF'] = '';
    $parentFolder = $_POST['pF'];
    $result = array();
    for($i = 0;isset($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]); $i++){
        $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
        $file_tmp_name = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $file_error = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
        if($file_size){
            $file_ex = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                
            $file_uploaded_by = $_SESSION['id'];
            $file_ex_lc = strtolower($file_ex);
            $dissalowed_exs = array("php", "hmtl", "js", "css", "asp", "aspx", "swf", "htm", "xhtml", "jhtml");
            if(!in_array($file_ex_lc, $dissalowed_exs)){
                $file_new_name = $file_name.uniqid("-", true);
                $file_path = $file_new_name.".".$file_ex;
                $query = "INSERT INTO `files`(`id`, `name`, `src`, `uploadDate`, `size`, `type`, `downloads`, `uploadedBy`, `deletedOn`, `status`, `parentFolder`,`JSON`) VALUES (NULL,'".$file_name."','".$file_path."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."','".$file_size."','".$file_type."',0,".$file_uploaded_by.", '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', 0, '$parentFolder', '{\"allowed\":[]}');";
                if($conn->query($query)){

                }else{
                    $result[$i] = returnMSG('failed', $conn->error);
                }
                if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name,"../uploads/files/".$file_path)){

                }else{
                    $result[$i] = returnMSG('failed', 'Unable to move file!');
                }
            }else{
                $result[$i] = returnMSG('failed', 'File type not allowed, put the file in an archive and try again!');
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    $result = returnMSG('redirect', 'You are not logged in or the session has expired!');
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: is it possible your server is plainly running out of RAM? It's also hard to rule out your code (most PHP in this world *is* buggy), but we don't know your code :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller most likely not since the server has 8GB of ram and the files stop uploading at exactly 100MB. Also transfering files (I have tested up to 20GB) with filezilla worked without a problem.

Comment: Which `php.ini` file did you edit? IME there can be two or more installed but only one is relevant. Have you searched for others? Have you restarted apache since making the change? In certain circumstances this is necessary.

Comment: What is the `memory_limit` in your php.ini? I'm afraid 100M.

Comment: DUPLICATE OF SAME ASKED QUESTION AT https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/713812/100397