# File upload freezes with files >= 100MB

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, php

So I have a website where you can upload files,
when you start an upload a progress bar pops up.

If a file or group of files selected at once is less than 100MB the upload goes through and completes without a problem.

If they are over 100MB the upload freezes at 0%.

I have set

> post_max_size = 200G

> upload_max_filesize = 200G

> memory_limit=4096M

Executing **php --version** gives the following output

> PHP 8.1.2 (cli) (built: Jul 21 2022 12:10:37) (NTS)
> Copyright (c) The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v8.1.2, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

The code I use for the upload works with any file on my PC using XAMPP.

For my server I use a RaspberryPI 4.

Any help with solving this problem would be appreciated.

Also the php code:

```php
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION))session_start();
function returnMSG($status, $message){
    $result = array();
    $result['status'] = $status;
    $result['error'] = $message;
    return $result;
}
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    include "data.php";
    $limit = $fileLimit[$_SESSION['role']];
    $currData = 0;
    include "connect.php";
    $conn = connect("upload"); // custom function
    if(!isset($_POST['pF']))$_POST['pF'] = '';
    $parentFolder = $_POST['pF'];
    $result = array();
    for($i = 0;isset($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]); $i++){
        $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
        $file_tmp_name = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $file_error = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
        if($file_size){
            $file_ex = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                
            $file_uploaded_by = $_SESSION['id'];
            $file_ex_lc = strtolower($file_ex);
            $dissalowed_exs = array("php", "hmtl", "js", "css", "asp", "aspx", "swf", "htm", "xhtml", "jhtml");
            if(!in_array($file_ex_lc, $dissalowed_exs)){
                $file_new_name = $file_name.uniqid("-", true);
                $file_path = $file_new_name.".".$file_ex;
                $query = "INSERT INTO `files`(`id`, `name`, `src`, `uploadDate`, `size`, `type`, `downloads`, `uploadedBy`, `deletedOn`, `status`, `parentFolder`,`JSON`) VALUES (NULL,'".$file_name."','".$file_path."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."','".$file_size."','".$file_type."',0,".$file_uploaded_by.", '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', 0, '$parentFolder', '{\"allowed\":[]}');";
                if($conn->query($query)){

                }else{
                    $result[$i] = returnMSG('failed', $conn->error);
                }
                if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name,"../uploads/files/".$file_path)){

                }else{
                    $result[$i] = returnMSG('failed', 'Unable to move file!');
                }
            }else{
                $result[$i] = returnMSG('failed', 'File type not allowed, put the file in an archive and try again!');
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    $result = returnMSG('redirect', 'You are not logged in or the session has expired!');
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

This is a repost since I can't get access to my other profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added to the apache2.conf file

```
<Directory **absolute upload folder path**>
        LimitRequestBody 0
</Directory>
```